# Is it possible to DESIGN and SEND a survey from Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to DESIGN and SEND a survey from Tableau, or just ANALYZE responses (data) to an existing survey which was designed and sent from another database (eg, SurveyMonkey)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Tableau would only be for the data analysis post-survey.